# Filter table by string "starting with" in Big Query

Tags: google-bigquery, where-clause, stringr

I would like to implement in BigQuery the same function I can find in [stringr (R package)](https://stringr.tidyverse.org/reference/str_starts.html) - as `str_starts()`

I would like to filter a table for all the string rows *starting with* "Sport - ".

I use the expression `LIKE` but I am not sure it works correctly...

```
SELECT *
FROM table_1
WHERE string LIKE '%Sport - %'
```

Comment: BigQuery provides **STARTS_WITH()** built-in function.   See https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#starts_with

Comment: The `LIKE` operator may be sufficient to reach your goal with `WHERE string LIKE 'Sport - %'` (note that there is no percent on the beginning of the filtrer string, implying you're looking for a match only for strings that _starts with_ `"Sport - "`). If you have to care about collation order, there is limitations with the `LIKE` operator, see [https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#like_operator](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/operators#like_operator).

Answer (score 2):

You can use REGEXP_CONTAINS on your where clause

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE REGEXP_CONTAINS(Team,r'^Sport\s-\s')
```

Reference:
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_contains

Answer (score 0):

You can use the function STARTS_WITH

```
SELECT
  *
FROM
  table_1
WHERE
  STARTS_WITH(string, "Sport")
```

Comment: As the use of `STARTS_WITH` is an appropriate way here, your answer does not exactly answer the question. The question is manly about the correct way to filter results where `string`  starts with the string `"Sport - "`, your example code here only do that for `"Sport"`. Your answer may also have to addresses the case of blank characters (space, tabs, etc.)  here.